# Tensorflow's gradient_override_map function

Tags: python, tensorflow

Can someone explain me `gradient_override_map` function in TensorFlow?
I couldn't understand its usage precisely.

I see code usage as:

```
with G.gradient_override_map({"Floor": "Identity"}):
    return tf.reduce_mean(SomeVals) * SomeOtherVal
```

What exactly is happening here? What is `Identity`?

Comment: Just for clarification purposes, the naming "Identity" of the operation does not matter. It is changing the gradient op of all identity ops in the block

Answer (score 8):

Both "Floor" and "Identity" are type strings of operations, the former is corresponding to *tf.floor* while the latter *tf.identity*. **So the function of your code, I guess, is to substitute *tf.identity*'s back-propagated gradient(BPG for short) calculation mechanism for BPG calculation mechanism of *tf.floor* operations within graph G while passing forward output of *tf.reduce_mean***. It seems a little weird since in all applications of `gradient_override_map` I've found so far, the key of op_type_map is always identical to the type string of the operation used to produce an output in the context. By this I mean I'm more familiar with scenarios with `tf.floor(SomeVals)` returned, instead of `tf.reduce_mean(SomeVals)`.

What `gradient_override_map({op_A_type: op_B_type})` does is to replace op_A's BPG calculation mechanism with op_B's while remaining op_A_type's forward propagation calculation mechanism. A common application of gradient_override_map is shown in lahwran's answer.

```
@tf.RegisterGradient("CustomGrad")
def _const_mul_grad(unused_op, grad):
    return 5.0 * grad

g = tf.get_default_graph()
with g.gradient_override_map({"Identity": "CustomGrad"}):
    output = tf.identity(input, name="Identity")
```

by

```
@tf.RegisterGradient("CustomGrad")
def _const_mul_grad(unused_op, grad):
    return 5.0 * grad
```

the decorator, `tf.RegisterGradient("CustomGrad")` registers the gradient function defined by `_const_mul_grad(unused_op, grad)` for a customized op type -- "CustomGrad",

while

```
g = tf.get_default_graph()
with g.gradient_override_map({"Identity": "CustomGrad"}):
    output = tf.identity(input, name="Identity")
```

assures outputs of all operations (in graph g) with string type "Identity" (*tf.identity*) are as they were whereas BPG calculation mechanism of *tf.identity*s replaced by BPG calculation mechanism of operation with string type "CustomGrad".

P.S.

1. The type string of an op corresponds to the `OpDef.name` field for the proto that defines the operation. To find an op's `OpDef.name` , please refer to MingXing's answer under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013530/tensorflow-gradient-override-map-cannot-override-op-tf-stack-s-backward-gradie)
2. It is not necessary to declare the name of *tf.identity* operation since the arg 'name' in *tf.identity* is optional.

Comment: I know it’s just an example, but isn’t it a bit dangerous to change the gradient of the identity function? I mean, the identity function is the function that you should be able to apply without causing any changes, so it can in principle have been used an arbitrary number of times in any TF function since it doesn’t change anything, right? Changing its gradient makes it suddenly have an effect, which feels like it may give rise to unexpected consequences.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye your worry is reasonable, the identity function in computation graph g has indeed been manually edited. However, it is not beyond our control since we have every knowledge of the Opt: the forward function (remaining unchanged), the backward gradient (as we defined). All we need is to deal with the changed Opt with extra caution.

Answer (score 2):

As best as I can tell, gradient_override_map allows you to say "in this context, any time you would use the gradient of X, instead use the gradient of Y". which means you still need the *gradient* of Y to be the gradient you want to use.

This is an example I've seen floating around while looking for how this works:

```
@tf.RegisterGradient("CustomGrad")
def _const_mul_grad(unused_op, grad):
    return 5.0 * grad

g = tf.get_default_graph()
with g.gradient_override_map({"Identity": "CustomGrad"}):
    output = tf.identity(input, name="Identity")
```

cite: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43948872/1102705

`RegisterGradient()` allows you to register the gradient of a new op you're defining, thereby allowing you to have an op that has the gradient you wanted, and then you can use that op in the gradient override map. It's kind of clunky - you're defining an op with no forward pass.

Something I'm not clear on is whether the name="Identity" is actually necessary.