# Tensorflow: gradient_override_map cannot override op tf.stack 's backward gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to edit `tf.stack` op's backward gradient calculation mechanism with `tf.RegisterGradient`and`tf.gradient_override_map`, here are my codes:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class SynthGradBuilder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num_calls = 0

    def __call__(self, x, l=1.0):
        op_name = "SynthGrad%d" % self.num_calls
        @tf.RegisterGradient(op_name)
        def _grad_synth(op, grad):
            return grad[0]

        g = tf.get_default_graph()
        with g.gradient_override_map({"stack": op_name}):
            y = tf.stack([x,x])

        self.num_calls += 1
        return y

GradSys = SynthGradBuilder()
```

in another script, I wrote

```
import tensorflow as tf
from gradient_synthesizer import GradSys

x = tf.Variable([1,2])
y = GradSys(x, l=1)
z = tf.stack([x,x])


grad = tf.gradients(y, x, grad_ys=[[tf.convert_to_tensor([3, 4]), 
                              tf.convert_to_tensor([6, 8])]])
grad_stack = tf.gradients(z, x, grad_ys=[[tf.convert_to_tensor([3, 4]), 
                              tf.convert_to_tensor([6, 8])]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print "grad bp: ", sess.run(grad)
    print "grad_stack: ", sess.run(grad_stack)
    print "y: ", sess.run(y)
```

The expected output should be:

```
grad bp: [3,4];
grad_stack: [3+6, 4+8] = [9, 12];
y: [[1,2], [1,2]];
```

What I actually got from the code was:

[image: my result]

indicating that `tf.stack`'s backward gradients were not replaced at all, which was opposite to my expectation.

I'm not sure if such discrepancy was brought by falsely using "stack" as the type string of operation `tf.stack`, I carried out an experiment in the following way:

[image: my validation]

The first item describing tensor y, the "stack:0" suggests op `tf.stack` 's registered name is "stack", which is also its type string. So it seems it is not "stack"'s fault.

I am at a loss to figure out the causes of my codes' problem. I wonder if anyone can help me with that.

Comment: This is really strange. It seems that `def _grad_synth(op, grad)` is actually never called. Would be curious to know if you could find out the cause and fix it. I will try from my side also. And will let you know if there is something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tl;dr: The correct code should be:

```
@tf.RegisterGradient(op_name)
def _grad_synth(op, grad):
  x, y = tf.unstack(grad)
  return [x, tf.zeros_like(y)]

g = tf.get_default_graph()
with g.gradient_override_map({"Pack": op_name}):
  y = tf.stack([x, x])
```

---

Because this is a quite common question, I want to explain a little bit more details:

There are two main issues in your original code:

1. Wrong usage of `gradient_override_map`:

The actual OP name for `tf.stack` is `Pack` (not `Stack`), so you need to ovrride `Pack` instead of `Stack`:

```
`g.gradient_override_map({"Pack": op_name})`.
```

You may wonder how do I know the actual OP name? Well, a simple way is to prober the GraphDef by running the following code:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  x = tf.constant(0)
  y = tf.stack([x, x])
  print(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def())
```

2. Wrong gradient function:

The original gradients for `Pack` is a simple `Unpack` ([official code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/cc/gradients/array_grad.cc)). In your case, you still need to first unpack the gradients, but only propogate the FIRST part:

```
@tf.RegisterGradient(op_name)
def _grad_synth(op, grad):
  x, y = tf.unstack(grad)
  return [x, tf.zeros_like(y)]
```

Note, this code works perfectly for your case. However, if you want to support any length of stack, you can use a slightly more complicated version:

```
@tf.RegisterGradient(op_name)
def _grad_synth(op, grad):
  x_list = tf.unstack(grad)
  for i in range(1, len(x_list)):
    x_list[i] = tf.zeros_like(x_list[i])
  return x_list
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your method is a nice fit for my issue! Still curious about the "stack:0" I got by printing the op, what is it? When I use the name "stack" to retrieve the op with `tf.Graph.get_operation_by_name`, it returns the op correctly.